# Counting zeros in a recursive manner

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to count TRAILING zeros from a recursive manner. Basically I split the final recursive result and then created a var counter that will count all the zeros.

```
function countingZeros(n) {
  if (n < 0) {
    // Termination condition to prevent infinite recursion
    return;
  }
  // Base case
  if (n === 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  // Recursive case
  let final = n * countingZeros(n -1);

  let counter = 0;

  String(final).split('').forEach(function(item){
    item === 0 ? counter++ : counter;
  });

  return counter;
}

countingZeros(12) // => suppose to output 2 since there are 2 trailing zeros from 479001600 but got 0

countingZeros(6) // => suppose to get 1 since 720 is the final result.
```

I am expecting to get 2 in return as the counter must return but instead I got 0. Any idea what am I missing on my function? How should I fix it?

Comment: I'm really confused, you didn't mention anything about factorials but given your examples at the bottom I assume they are relevant? If I understand correctly, basically you want a function that takes a non-negative integer, computes the factorial, and then returns the number of trailing 0s in that value?

Comment: You should have two functions: `factorial(n) -> factorial of n` and `countingZeros(n)` that call `factorial` and return the count of the trailing 0s of the return value. (`countingZeros` won't be recursive, only `factorial` will).

Comment: Correct. thays right

Comment: Your base case also looks wrong.  0! = 1, which has no trailing zeros.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're working too hard.  First of all, in response to a comment, you don't actually need to calculate the factorial, since all you really need is to count factors of 5 and of 2.  And since there are many more factors of 2, your real answer is just counting factors of 5.  But each factor of 5 must be a factor of one of {1, 2, 3, ... n}, so we just have to add up the highest powers of five that evenly divide into each of {1, 2, 3, ... n}.

We can do that with some simple recursion:

```
 const fiveFactors = (n, acc = 0) => (n % 5 == 0) 
       ? fiveFactors(n / 5, acc + 1) 
       : acc
 const factZeros = (n, acc = 0) => (n > 0) 
       ? factZeros(n - 1, acc + fiveFactors(n)) 
       : acc

 factZeros(1000) //=> 249
```

Note that both functions are eligible for tail-call optimization.

Also, although this does involve a double recursion, it's not really ill-performant.  Four out of five times, the internal recursion stops on the first call, and of the remainder, four out of five stop on the second call, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to count the number of zeroes using string functions(i will assume, you forgot to include the factorial method. Correct flow could have been- you first pass the input to a factorial method and pass output from factorial method to countingZeros method). Anyways as stated already in other answer, you don't really need to calculate the factorial product to count the trailing zeroes.

Here a sample to count the number of trailing zeroes in n!

```
        temp = 5;
        zeroes = 0;
        //counting the sum of multiples of 5,5^2,5^3....present in n!
        while(n>=temp){
            fives = n/temp;
            zeroes = zeroes + fives;
            temp = temp*5;  
        }
        printf("%d",zeroes);
```

Note that each multiple of 5 in the factorial product will contribute 1 to the number of trailing zeros. On top of this, each multiple of 25 will contribute an additional 1 to the number of trailing zeros. Then, each multiple of 125 will contribute another 1 to the number of trailing zeros, and so on.

Here's a great link to understand the concept behind this:
https://brilliant.org/wiki/trailing-number-of-zeros/